# Generating and shifting the circle in loop in phaser 2

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am new to phaser 2.3.x. These are the five positions:

**1   2   3   4   5**.

My problem is - I want to generate a circle_no_1 sprite at position 1. After two second I want to shift the circle_no_1 to position 2 and at the same time generate another circle_no_2 at position 1. Again after 2 second I want to generate the circle_no_3 at position 1 and shift circle_no_2 at 2 position and circle_no_1 at third position and so on in **LOOP**.

Here what I tried :- I created an event loop of 2 second in `create()` function of GameState. and call another function `updateCirclePosition()` at every two second. I created a group named `this.circleGroup = this.add.group()`.
In method `updateCirclePosition()` on every call I created a circle and add in the group `this.circleGroup` and I tweened the whole group. But I am not able to make a loop i.e. When circle_no_1 reaches to 5th position then it should return back to the first position and also I am not able to create all the circles.

```
var GameState = {

  create:function(){
        ------
        this.circle1;
        this.circle2;
        this.circle3;
        this.circle4;
        this.circle5;

        this.isCircle1Created = false
        this.isCircle2Created = false
        this.isCircle3Created = false
        this.isCircle4Created = false
        this.isCircle5Created = false

        this.circleGroup = this.add.group();
        this.circleGroupTween = this.add.tween(this.circleGroup);

        this.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, this.updateCirclePosition, this);
        ------
  },
  updateCirclePosition:function(){
        if(this.isCircle1Created == false){
            this.circle1 = this.add.sprite(30,40,'circle1')
            this.isCircle1Created = true;
            this.circleGroup.add(this.circle1)
        }
        else if(this.isCircle2Created == false){
            this.circle2 = this.add.sprite(30,40,'circle2')
            this.isCircle2Created = true;
            this.circleGroup.add(this.circle2)

        }
        else if(this.isCircle3Created == false){
            this.circle3 = this.add.sprite(30,40,'circle3')
            this.isCircle3Created = true;
            this.circleGroup.add(this.circle3)
        }
        else if(this.isCircle4Created == false){
            this.circle4 = this.add.sprite(30,40,'circle4')
            this.isCircle4Created = true;
            this.circleGroup.add(this.circle4)
        }
        else if(this.isCircle35Created == false){
            this.circle5 = this.add.sprite(30,40,'circle5')
            this.isCircle5Created = true;
            this.circleGroup.add(this.circle5)
        }
        this.circleGroupTween.to({y:200},400)
        this.circleGroupTween.start();
  }
}
```

How can I do it in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

it is very often unnecessary to write code that way, it makes the project awfully difficult to maintain and causes unnecessary trouble: more time to make changes, poor readability and easy to make mistakes e.g. this.isCircle35Created

a good idea would be to make an array of circles

```
this.circles = []
```

to add a circle you've created use

```
this.circles.push(circle)
```

when you have to count how many circles already exist, use

```
this.circles.length
```

e.g. when 2 circles exist, you can use `this.circles.length + 1` to get *3* that you need for your "circle3" string.

from here there are a few options:

*option 1*. make a variable to track whether you're adding or removing circles

```
this.addingCircles = true
```

so your logic is the following:

- If adding circles, create a circle and move the existing ones down; repeat until you have 5 circles
- Change `this.addingCircles` to false
- If not adding circles, move the last circle back to where it was created, and remove it upon completing the tween; repeat until there are no circles left
- Change `this.addingCircles` to true

*option 2*. create all circles immediately at the start, and use a tween for each of them with a delay based on their index. e.g. with `this.circles.length * 2000` delay the first circle would have 0, the second one would wait 2000ms before starting the tween

*option 3*. if you can switch to Phaser 3, i'd recommend doing that as it has [timelines](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/tweens/timelines/simple%20timeline%208.js) that make this easier

Comment: thanks buddy.. I followed you as u said to make an array of the circle sprite and it worked

Comment: nice, feel free to take a look at array's shift/pop/slice methods as they are useful for obtaining first/last/arbitrary elements and shifting the other, in a single line of code. remember to upvote questions/answers you find helpful, and to mark answers 'accepted' if they solve the original question!

Answer (score 0):

this `this.tweenCircleGroup` will be called after every 5 second from the `create method` like `this.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 5, this.tweenCircleGroup, this);`

```
tweenCircleGroup: function () {
        // here I am checking if all the circles is created or not
        if (this.totCircle < 5) {
            var circle = this.add.sprite(30, 90, 'circle1')
            circle.anchor.setTo(0.5)
            this.circlesArray.push(circle)
            this.totCircle++;
        } else {
            // once all the circle is created then we move the sprite
            // one position ahead and move the last circle(i.e. this.circlesArray[0] ) at the first position (i.e. this.circlesArray[4] )
            var temp = this.circlesArray[0];
            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                this.circlesArray[i - 1] = this.circlesArray[i]
            }

            this.circlesArray[4] = temp;
            // this line will move the firstly created circle at the first position
            this.circlesArray[4].position.y = 90;
        }
        // below code will tween all the circles inside the array
        var tween;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.circlesArray.length; i++) {
            tween = this.add.tween(this.circlesArray[i])
            tween.to({ y: "+40" }, 3000)
            tween.start();
        }

    }
```