# Uncaught TypeError: this._tweens[i].update is not a function at Phaser.TweenManager.update

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am working with phaser 2.3.0. I am stuck with a situation. I am applying tween on multiple sprites at a time with the following code:-

```
var GameState = {

  create:function(){
        ------
        this.circle1;
        this.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, this.updateCirclePosition, this);
        ------
  },
  updateCirclePosition:function(){
            this.circle1 = this.add.sprite(30,40,'circle1')
            this.tweenCircle1 = this.tweens.add({
                targets: [this.circle1], // or targets: this.circle1
                y: '+=50',
                duration: 400,
                ease: 'Linear'
            });
  }
}
```

But it is not working. It only creating the sprite image but not applying any tween on it and after creating the sprite it is showing the following error message `phaser.js:47296 Uncaught TypeError: this._tweens[i].update is not a function
    at Phaser.TweenManager.update`. When I applied the following code it is working fine

```
   this.tweenCircle1 = this.add.tween(this.circle1)
   this.tweenCircle1.to({y:90},400);
   this.tweenCircle1.start();
```

What is the problem in the above code which is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
this.tweenCircle1 = this.tweens.add({
    targets: [this.circle1], // or targets: this.circle1
    y: '+=50',
    duration: 400,
    ease: 'Linear'
});
```

is the code for Phaser 3

if you want to use Phaser 2 CE, the code would look something like this

```
this.add.tween(this.circle1).to({ y: '+50' }, 400, 'Linear', true)
```

[Tween.to args](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Tween.html#to) are the following:

```
to(properties [, duration] [, ease] [, autoStart] [, delay] [, repeat] [, yoyo])
```

Comment: My task is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58413095/generating-and-shifting-the-circle-in-loop-in-phaser-2) . Can I apply tween on multiple sprites at the same time? And it's hard to implement by making a dynamic group of sprites and apply tween on the group object.

Comment: i believe individual tweens would be appropriate here, then you could either [chain them](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/tweens/chained-tweens) or try to keep them in sync with initial delay based on their index (option 2 in the answer to the question you linked)